# How can I turn this javascript into a function? Is it already a function? A few very basic questions about js structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am learning javascript, and am trying to adjust the following:

```
$('#myform').change(function() {
    if ($('#sv_I4b').attr('checked')||$('#sv_I4c').attr('checked')){
        $('#sv_I5').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('#sv_I5').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

To be a a function with a name that I can call on different events, such as page load etc.

I don't yet fully understand each element, but I know that:

```
    if ($('#sv_I4b').attr('checked')||$('#sv_I4c').attr('checked')){
        $('#sv_I5').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('#sv_I5').addClass('hidden');
    }
```

is the core "logic" of the function: `if (condition) {then this} else {that}`

and more or less understand what is happening there. Which leaves the bounding javascript (is there better terminology than that?):

`$('#myform').change(function() {...});`

**My Questions (are the following true etc):**

- The dollar I think denotes that it is jQuery
- The id my form obviously
  pertains the script to events within that form (namespace?)
- [.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)  seems to be, a trigger that listens to ... any change taking place
  within #myform? so every time a change happens within #myform this
  runs? That seems inefficient
- function() I don't yet understand what
  an anonymous or empty function does, just defines what is contained
  in {} as a function?

My goal: to be able to have something like

```
function myfunction()
{
if ($('#sv_I4b').attr('checked')||$('#sv_I4c').attr('checked')){
        $('#sv_I5').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('#sv_I5').addClass('hidden');
    }
}
```

and then

```
$(function() {myfunction});
```

so I can call that function on page load, but I don't wan't to loose the functionality the .change syntax is providing me (that it changes as the user interacts with the elements on the page also.

Apologies for the general and cumbersome levels of ignorance

Comment: You seem to have understood everything well, to _invoke_ or _call_ (both mean pratically the same thing) your _function_ `myfunction`, you'd write `myfunction()`. i.e. `myfunction` references the function, `()` invokes it. An empty function is a function that performs no action (invoking it will still use a tiny bit of time). An anonymous function is a function that you've not given a name to, and have either assigned as a variable (use as reference) or invoking immediately (`()` straight after definition)

Comment: Do not use `attr` for the `checked` *property* …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guessed how to define the function correctly — that is,

```
function myfunction()
{
if ($('#sv_I4b').attr('checked')||$('#sv_I4c').attr('checked')){
        $('#sv_I5').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('#sv_I5').addClass('hidden');
    }
}
```

works just fine. However, this:

```
$(function() {myfunction});
```

Should be written as:

```
$(myfunction);  // Run on page load.
$('#myform').change(myfunction);  // ...and also run it when the form changes.
```

However, that second line won't actually work until the page has loaded unless the form exists at the time the script runs, so you may want to change it to this:

```
$(function() {  // On page load, run this anonymous function:
    myfunction();  // Run the function now (where now, at this point, is page load).
    $('#myform').change(myfunction);  // ...as well as when the form changes.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation - a follow up: is there any undesirability to triggering a function every time anything changes in a form? If it's a large form (mine is) there will be a lot of changes, and my function only relates to a couple of elements. Is this bad form?

Comment: @Gideon: It's probably going to be fast enough. It's a quick test to check if the checkboxes are checked (no pun intended) and it's also pretty quick to add and remove classes. I wouldn't be worried about performance for such a small thing.

Comment: @Bergi: I felt introducing an unrelated change (since I did not write that code; it is in the initial question, and is unrelated to their problem) would clutter my answer.

Answer (score 1):

- **$** is shorthand notation for **jQuery**, and essentially namespaces any functions to the jQuery framework.
- my_form is a DOM selector. $('#my_form') wraps the matched DOM element up as a jQuery object, adding all sorts of useful methods and properties.
- **.change()** is an event listener which, as you guessed, watches for change events on that jQuery object. It is a little inefficient - take a look **.on()** instead.
- the most useful behaviour an anonymous function (closure) is to create private scope, something that javascript doesn't otherwise provide.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations, really helpful.